# curl get json returns 404

Tags: json, curl

I'm running a tomcat server with a REST service on localhost.

This url typed in the browser gives me a json response: `http://localhost:8080/a/rest/dataset/list`

But when I use curl: `curl http://localhost:8080/a/rest/dataset/list` the response is HTML code with a 404 error from the server.

What am I missing in the curl command?

Comment: Are there any expected HTTP parameters/cookies on the server side ?

Comment: Hi Halim, no there aren't.

Answer (score 1):

`Tomcat` may be waiting for a *specially formatted* HTTP request from the user. As you are expecting a response in `json`, you should probably forward the following argument to curl :

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Also, you may always specify to whatever HTTP server the response you are expecting him to return. A lot of back-end application based on HTTP are issuing a response given the HTTP request.

Comment: doh, after one hour staring at the screen: it was actually a typo in the path to the service. the server name was correct, so it got something, but did not return json. Thanks anyway Halim...